# How to change object name by adding new text to the original name

Tags: python, objects

This is an example of what i want, imagine that in my scene exist a cube and i just want change his name by adding text to his original name like "_something"

Example:

cube_something

How do i do this using Blender Phyton.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

first get a reference to the object.  By name you might use:

```
obj=bpy.data.objects['Cube'] # or
obj=bpy.context.selected_objects[0]
```

then append to the name:

```
obj.name = obj.name + "_something"
```

Comment: Thanks that works perfectly